# Efficient way to get the smallest N-th element(s)

Tags: c#, sorting, time-complexity

Given a string, what an efficient way is there to

- return the N-th lowest char in it (ASCII wise)?
- return the N-th lowset char**s** in it?

I have thought of sorting N iteration with insertion sort, or sorting quick sort, where the pivot is in the N-th position, but I had problem analyzing time complexity. Is there any other, more efficient way?

What will be the solution is it wasn't a string, but a list of decimals?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, have a look at [quickselect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect).

Comment: super. What will be the solution is it wasn't a string, but a list of decimals?

Comment: I am voting to reopen this question: I think this is a legitimate question about order statistics algorithms applied to small numbers; it is not "too localized" at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your strings are ASCII, you can do it using a [counting-sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) style algorithm. Make an array of 256 counters, go through the string, and increment a counter for each character's code that you find in the string. Now walk the array from zero, accumulating the counts that you've seen so far. When adding a counter for character `ch` causes your accumulated result cross over `N`, you know that `ch` is the `n`-th character if the string were sorted. This algorithm is `O(N)`, where `N` is the number of characters in your string. This is the time that it takes to build the array of counts.

Comment: super. What will be the solution is it wasn't a string, but a list of decimals?

Comment: @EladBenda If you have decimals bounded at `K`, you can stay with the same simple algorithm for `O(K)` complexity in both time and memory, or go for a [generalized selection (median of medians) algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm#Linear_general_selection_algorithm_-_Median_of_Medians_algorithm) which is considerably more complex.

Comment: what if the decimals are not bounded at `K`?

Comment: @EladBenda Generalized selection does not need them to be bounded at K, and gives you the same `O(N)` performance. It's a lot harder, though. You can also run a non-comparison sort (a bucket sort, a radix sort) on your decimals for a linear algorithm.

Comment: @EladBenda No, if you use `Dictionary<K,V>` in .NET, the keys are not going to come in order. If you use a sorted dictionary, on the other hand, then the insertion time is not going to be `O(1)`, bringing you back to `O(N*LogN)` - the same performance as when you comparison-sort.

Comment: how about that for getting the smallest n elements: creating Max heap from the first N elements. Then for each of the remainning: insert into the heap and remove the current max.

Comment: @EladBenda That's still `O(N*LogN)`